# iPhone code signing error

Tags: iphone, xcode, code-signing

I have been working with 2 developer ids for a certain project now. I had developed the app using the 1st Id and tested it even. I need to submit the app to the app store using the 2nd Id, now i have all the right certificates and provisioning profiles in the right place. And i have deleted all certificates and provisioning profiles of the 1st Id. But still i Get this error

```
[BEROR]Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution: Sam Sim' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain
```

iPhone Distribution: Sam Sim is of the 1st Developer Id which I have removed from keychain. Why cant xcode find the 2nd identity even though its present in the keychain

EDIT: might I also add that the first id is an Individual developer id where as the second is a Corporate developer id

Please help,
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you change the build settings for the target or project

> Target->Info->Build->Code Singing

Comment: If you are talking about Project->Edit Project Settings->Build->Code Signing->Code Signing Identity then yes it points to the right profile else I cant find target

Comment: Ok got it. I thought if i changed the Code signing settings it would reflect everywhere. but that does not seem to be the case. Thank you so much!